# Acces object atribute in generic funtion

Tags: generics, kotlin

How can I access object property in generic function? Code, I've currently made claims about `error: unresolved reference: name`. How can I make it work?
There is `where` keyword but i din't found much information about it.

```
fun <T> foo(t:T): String{
    return t.name
}

foo(object {
    val name = "Foo"
})
```

C++ equivalent:

```
struct {
    int name{10};
}a;

template<typename T>
int foo(T&t) {
    return t.name;
}

foo(a);
```

Comment: I don't know of any `where`-keyword... what do you mean? Note: generic type information is erased at runtime, so think of it as if you just have written `t: Any`. Clearly you can't access `Any.name` as it does not exist... You could access it via reflection though...

Comment: Note: if you do not require to support objects created via `object { val name : String }` then both shown answers will probably already suite your needs. If you require more, you need to take the reflection route.

Comment: Is it like that "generics" in kotlin are same shity generic like stuff like in Java?

Comment: basically yes, because it's just the same ;-) but in Kotlin you can also make use of [`reified` type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters).

Comment: I just started with this language and it seems I like it same as Java :D

Comment: it is similar to Java... I come from the Java-world and can just say: it's very easy to switch and it is way more convenient/pragmatic in many cases. I will add an answer just showing how you could deal with the generics part in Kotlin...

Comment: `reified` works with `inline fun` only. 
And again you cannot access members with even `reified`, you can access only the class information. like in java `T.class` won't be possible whereas with `reified` you can do `T::class.java`.

Comment: I though the point is to fix retarded Java quirks not to replicate them :D

Comment: well usually you have a type, do you? And if you have a type, you could use any of the shown answers. But your sample shows an anonymous type... and that's... well... special ;-)

Comment: the point is I don't have.

Comment: that's not completely true... actually you have one... but still: it is anonymous... you can't access it, except via reflection.

Comment: I know, wand I would like to stay only with this "implicit" type, cause its only onstance of it , and creating Java lovers factory bridge creator whatever to call it to thousends of fuctions its ridicouls and shadows the case i want to solve as possible as simple

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample how you could do it in Kotlin, using reflection (note: you don't even need that generic type information here the way you use that function):

```
fun foo(t : Any) = with(t::class.java.getDeclaredField("name")) {
  isAccessible = true
  get(t) as String
}
```

`with` is not really required. You can of course do it completely different. Just wanted to show how this could look like in Kotlin.

I said something of a `reified` type in the comments, but you actually don't need it here.

The biggest problem to solve your problem is, that you have an anonymous type, which basically narrows down the possible solutions to just "use reflection" ;-)

If you would have a type/interface as follows:

```
interface Nameable {
  val name : String
}
```

then you could change your `foo` method to:

```
fun foo(t : Nameable) = t.name
```

and calling it, would result in:

```
foo(object : Nameable {
  override val name = "Foo"
}
```

But still, it's not a C++-template and you would have to create lots of appropriate interfaces if you would like to be fully dynamic and you would have to use them when creating your anonymous types, etc. pp.

Comment: use refelection seems to be akward cause it's runtime stuff, definitly not needed there

Comment: I know... do you know [Kotlins Type-Safe Builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html)? It's not really the same, but it may help you solve your problem?

Comment: it might be what i need lets see

Comment: nope, it's not it requieres definitions of all the astaff apriori

Comment: yes... that is required... maybe [delegated properties in a map](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map) is something for you? (still you would need at least a basic type from which everyone else extends... or work (again) with reflection :-P )... and of course... it's still not equivalent, but may help to workaround the problem ;-)

Comment: you may also want to read about c++-templates and Kotlin here (from the lead language designer of Kotlin, Andrey Breslav): https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/on-generics/1137/4

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you will use Kotlin [reified type parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) in generics.

```
foo(object {
    val name = "Foo"
})


inline fun <reified T> foo(t: T): String =
    T::class.declaredMembers.find { it.name == "name" }!!
    .call(t) as String
```

The second option is to get `::class` directly from `t`

```
fun <T: Any> foo(t: T): String =
    t::class.declaredMembers.find { it.name == "name" }!!.call(t) as String
```

The third option is to provide an upper bound for you generic parameter:

```
foo( NameProvider {
    val name = "Foo"
})

interface NameProvider {
    val name: String
}

fun <T: NameProvider> foo(t: T): String = t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access some specific type's members, then you should apply an **upper bound to the type parameter**.
It is possible to implement like so:

```
fun <T : MyTypeThatHasNameProperty> foo(t: T): String{
    return t.name
}
```

Comment: with the given sample `object { val name = "Foo" }` this will not work however...

Comment: in c++ you've done it using template, so created a specific type that has `name` field. in the case of object expression precise type is anonymous, because it is "one-time" only. if some specific member is needed, than some specific type should be provided as a boundary.

Comment: it is same in the case of c++ example

Comment: sorry, may be I ain't right about c++: I'm not qualified with this language. but as far as I can understand, a pointer is used here

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `T` could be instance of any type at runtime. So you can't access the property.

You can do something like this though

```
fun <T : SomeType> foo(t: T): String {
    return t.name
}

open class SomeType(val name: String)

foo(SomeType("value"))
```

**EDIT:**
If you really want to achieve this using `non-named object` then I can think of something like this.

```
fun <T : BaseType> foo(t: T): String {
    return t.name
}

interface BaseType {
   val name: String
}

foo(object :BaseType {
        override val name = "value"
})
```

Comment: with the given sample `object { val name = "Foo" }` this will not work however...

Comment: @Roland Yes, Thats the reason I provided alternative approach. 
See the updated answer.

Comment: Your alteranet aproach wont help at all

Comment: @majkrzak Honestly I don't think you need to go with generics at all in your case.

Comment: Consider following object (in JSON) called a `{"foo":{"name":"Foo"}, "bar":{"name":"Bar"}}` Will be nice to handle it like `f(a.foo) f(b.foo)

Comment: maybe use an `interface` instead of an `abstract` type: `interface Nameable{ val name: String }`